# Datagrid scrolling in Windows s Mobile way to get rid of scroll bar?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a very simple form using the compact framework.  I have two search fields a search button and a datagrid.  The button sets the DataSource for a DataGrid on the form.  I know that I can set the height and width on the DataGrid but I don't want the user to have to use the scroll bars on the DataGrid as it has a few hundred records.  I just want the user to use the scroll bar on the form to scroll.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the behavior you want is for a vertical scroll bar that spans the total height of the form to navigate through the records of the `DataGrid`.  This `DataGrid` does not take up all the space on the form.

You could add a `VScrollBar` to the side of the form and set its Maximum to the total row count of your `DataGrid`.  Then attach to the `ValueChanged` event of the scroll bar and manipulate the selected row of your `DataGrid`.  This in effect would be mimicking the scrolling behavior of the `DataGrid`.

The tricky part is hiding the scroll bar of the `DataGrid`, as there is no property to hide it.  You can extend its width so that the scroll bar is rendered off screen, but remember to set the Form's `AutoScroll` property to `false` so that it does not render a Horizontal scroll bar that would reveal the `DataGrid` kludge.

Based on your application, you may want to look into using a `ListView` with the `View` property set to `Details`.  The `ListView` is much easier to manipulate in the compact framework and might fit your application better.  You can still use the same `VScrollBar` technique above and apply it to the `ListView` if you wish.

Comment: Your assumption is a bit wrong.  I want to use the Forms AutoScroll and hide the DataGrids scroll bar.  The DataGrid brings back about 700+ records so it takes up more than the whole visible area of the form.  Perhaps I need to find out how many rows are in the datagrid and see how large that would be in pixels and set the datagrids height property to rows * pixels per row.  Any ideas(I am not sure how to find out how many rows there are)

Answer (score 0):

You must get the rowcount from the DataSource. Cast it like the enclosed example to produce the row count: (rsMissingItems is a SqlCEResultSet object)

```
    Dim intRecCnt As Int32 = DirectCast(rsMissingItems.ResultSetView, ICollection).Count
```